# How can I show loading button (SVProgressHUD) in MainviewController while data is loading in the appDelegate?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have a welcomeViewController with 1 button, when click the button I load a TableView with some data.

This data is loaded from array, and this array is filled when I initialize my app on appDelegate->application -> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

The problem is that if i click this button before the data is loaded, the tableView appears empty.

What I need is show loading button (like SVProgressHUD) in the MainviewController while data is loading in the appDelegate.

Is it possible ?

ths.

```
#appDelegate.swift

    var wodsArray : [Wod] = []
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        getWodsFromDataBase()
        return true
    }

    func getWodsFromDataBase () {
        let wodDb = Database.database().reference().child("wods")
        let db = Database.database().reference();

        let recentPostsQuery = (db.child("wods").queryLimited(toFirst: 2))
        var exercises_temp : [Exercise] = []

        wodDb.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in let snapValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            let Bear_crawl = snapValue["Bear_crawl"]!
            let Romanian_deadlift = snapValue["Romanian_deadlift"]!

            let wod = Wod(
                Bear_crawl: Bear_crawl as! Int,
                Romanian_deadlift: Romanian_deadlift as! Int,
            )
            self.wodsArray.append(wod)
        }
```

Comment: It can't be helped if the data is not loaded, can it? You can check whether the data is loaded when the user presses the button and show a message saying "the data is still loading" if the data has not finished loading.

Comment: Ths, I Just eddited the question with this:  I need to show loading button (like SVProgressHUD) in the MainviewController while data is loading in the appDelegate